# Fazendo fadeIn em div de menu fixo scroll com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou tentando fazer com que meu menu fixo abra com fade ao rolar a página mais meu codigo não está funcionando, e como não entendo muito de JS estou pedindo aqui uma ajuda para tentar solucionar meu problema.

vamos lá!

segue o meu bootply para da uma visualizada!

[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/jVI7AZ9yJK)

queria que ao rolar a página meu menu fixo faça um fade, e ao voltar ele volte normal e fixe no topo!

alguém poderia me da esse help?

Answer (score 1):

Antes de dar um `fadein` você precisa que o elemento não esteja sendo exibido.

Fiz um exemplo diretamente no seu código, segue o link [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/6gvHVqazHG)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: @MoisesGame ficou massa, mais ai vem um outro problema, eu quero que depois que ele apareça ele fique fixo, não suma ao mover a rolagem, só é para sumir quando voltar pro topo! .

Comment: @LucianoOliveiraLima ele está fazendo isso, veja se o conteúdo maior, pode ser sua resolução, tente diminuir a janela.